# Locally setting the line width in a paragraph

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

How can I make a specific paragraph have a specific line width?

Comment: You need the paragraph to be able to span across pages?

Comment: In this particular case no span is ok.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `\parbox{<linewidth>}{<content>}` for the paragraph. Alternatively you can use the very similar `minipage` environment which also takes the line width as first argument. However, both do not allow page breaks in the paragraph. Also have a look on the `quote` and `quotation` environments which narrow the paragraph width.

Comment: `\parbox` and `minipage` cannot span across pages.

Comment: @xport: In this case I would recommend `framed`.. Oh wait ;-)

Comment: @xport: I just figured that `\par\begingroup\hsize=<width> ... \par\endgroup` might be also do it and support page breaks. I'm not 100% sure if it is OK this way or if it needs extra care. Anyway, `\textwidth`, `\columnwidth` and `\linewidth` should all be set to `\hsize` as well, I think.

Comment: I tried this but it had strange side effects. A) The lineskip was reduced. B) In addition to the paragraph inside `{<content<}` the next paragraph was also affected. Only the second paragraph after the closing `}` was back to normal.

Answer (score 8):

The method with `\leftskip` and `\rightskip` doesn't work if the reduced width part of the document contains lists. In this case it's best to define an environment based on `list`:

```
\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{setpar}{left}[0pt]{\leftmargin=#1}
\define@key{setpar}{right}[0pt]{\rightmargin=#1}
\define@key{setpar}{both}{\leftmargin=#1\relax\rightmargin=#1}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{narrow}[1][]
  {\list{}{\setkeys{setpar}{left,right}%
     \setkeys{setpar}{#1}%
     \listparindent=\parindent
     \topsep=0pt
     \partopsep=0pt
     \parsep=\parskip}\item\relax\hspace*{\listparindent}\ignorespaces}
  {\endlist}
```

One can specify the settings in the following ways, that should be easily understood:

```
  \begin{narrow}[left=1cm]
  \begin{narrow}[right=2cm]
  \begin{narrow}[both=1cm]
  \begin{narrow}[left=2cm,right=1cm]
```

and lists inside the environment will work properly.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\leftskip=1cm
\blindtext

\rightskip=1cm
\blindtext

\leftskip=0pt\rightskip=0pt
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good feature: The paragraph can span across pages and be enclosed by a fancy frame.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed,lipsum,xcolor}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]{%
\def\FrameCommand{{\color{red}\vrule width 3pt}\hspace{0pt}\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{yellow}}%
\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}}
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{leftbar}[0.5\linewidth]
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{leftbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I much prefer the `mdframed` approach to defining new frame environments: `framed`'s approach is hard to read...